# How can I get all postal_codes for specific locality using place details API

Tags: google-places-api, google-places-autocomplete

when I post to "place details API" to get all the details for a locality using the PlaceId, some localities return with postal_code and others not. the localities that doesn't come with postal_code, has actually multiple postal_codes. so how can I get all the postal_codes for specific locality

Example: Washington (country:us) or Liverpool (country:gb)

I tried to get postal code or postal code prefix, but it doesn't work for me, only for localities that has many postal_codes. so please advise or if you tried any work around.

Comment: Can you provide a sample request? So that I can take a look into it also on my end.

Comment: According to the [docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/requests-reverse-geocoding#:~:text=for%20the%20entity.-,locality,-indicates%20an%20incorporated), "`locality` indicates an incorporated city or town political entity.". What I mean by quoting this is that locality for different places vary. This could mean that some localities does not have postal codes. So if you can't have postal codes for some localities, it could mean that it is working as intended.

Answer (score 1):

This use case is not supported by the Google Maps Geocoding or Places APIs.

These APIs provide details an individual place and *its address*, extending the concept of *address* beyond postal addresses so that a `locality` is augmented by providing with those political features that contain it.

If *and only if* a locally is fully contained by a single `postal_code`, then it is considered *part of the locality's address* and returned along with the other containing political features. Otherwise, it is the other way around: the `locality` would be part of the `postal_code`'s *address*.

To obtain a comprehensive list of postal codes in a city, a different API would be necessary.